# Assignment help updating amounts of each item for "shipments" and "orders" in a specific city

Tags: c++, orders

My assignment asks that I create a file with a list of records in a file called "ITEMRECORD.txt" which I have below:

```
    type warehouse amt1 amt2 amt3
    -----------------------------
    s    NewYork    23   14   1
    s    Miami      25   25   25
    s    LosAngeles 40   13   17
    s    Houston    100  30   10
    s    Chicago    42   23   19
    s    NewYork    0    0    15
    s    Miami      13   17   21
    o    LosAngeles 15   10   15
    o    NewYork    12   24   8
    o    Houston    75   45   10
    o    Chicago    20   15   15
    o    NewYork    15   0    0
    s    LosAngeles 10   20   10
    s    Houston    0    30   40
    o    NewYork    15   15   25
    o    Chicago    75   30   40
    s    NewYork    20   15   20
    o    Houston    10   20   10
```

I was able to write the code for reading in each line of text and numbers and distinguishing between "shipments" and "orders"

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;
    ifstream itemRec;

    struct record
    {
        char type;
        string warehouse[5] = {"NewYork", "LosAngeles", "Miami", "Houston",    "Chicago"};
        int amt[3] = {0,0,0};
    };
    struct price {
        double price;
    };

    int main ()
    {
        itemRec.open("ITEMRECORD.txt");
        record records;
        price item[3];

        string city1;
        int amt1, amt2, amt3;

        if(!itemRec)
        {
            cout << "Cannot open the record of items file!! Check file please!" << endl;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            itemRec >> item[i].price;
        }

        while (itemRec >> records.type)
        {

            if (records.type == 's')                         // READING IN A      SINGLE SHIPMENT CARD
            {       
                itemRec >>  city1;
                for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
                {
                    if (city1 == records.warehouse[i])
                    {
                            itemRec >> records.amt[0];
                            itemRec >> records.amt[1];
                            itemRec >> records.amt[2];
                    }
                }
            cout << records.type <<"\t" << city1 << "\t" << records.amt[0] << "\t" << records.amt[1] << "\t" << records.amt[2] << endl;
            }
            else if (records.type == 'o')                           // READING IN A SINGLE ORDER CARD
            {
                itemRec >>  city1;
                for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
                {
                    if (city1 == records.warehouse[i])
                    {
                            itemRec >> records.amt[0];
                            itemRec >> records.amt[1];
                            itemRec >> records.amt[2];  
                    }
                }
            cout << records.type <<"\t" << city1 << "\t" << records.amt[0] << "\t" << records.amt[1] << "\t" << records.amt[2] << endl;
            }
        }
```

However, the part that I am having trouble with is, as each card is being read in to update the number of items in each warehouse. For example, the first line is
`s   NewYork   23   14   1` when it sees `s    NewYork    0    0    15` I want the program to update the number in amt1, amt2, amt3 to `23    14   16` respectively.

How do I begin writing the code for updating those amounts for a specific city when found?

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for. _the program will update the number_ you mean that's what is ACTUALLY happening or that's what you WANT to happen?

Comment: I apologize for not making it clear enough, but that is what I WANT to happen.

Comment: @FirstStep I have created an array of the warehouses and first made sure that the city read in, is inside the array. Then I want it go through each line whenever it finds a match to update the amounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you find, you are assigning it right away and removing the old value:

```
if (city1 == records.warehouse[i])
{
    itemRec >> records.amt[0];
    itemRec >> records.amt[1];
    itemRec >> records.amt[2];
}
```

So do this instead:

```
if (city1 == records.warehouse[i])
{
     itemRec >> temp1; // declare a place holder
     itemRec >> temp2;
     itemRec >> temp3;

     records.amt[0] += temp1; // add the holder's value to the current value
     records.amt[1] += temp2;
     records.amt[2] += temp3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped a lot. It makes a lot more sense now of why you would create a temporary variable first and then add to the current value. Now, however, it's adding it to each line, rather than updating by city.

Comment: It should not do that since you are checking `if (city1 == records.warehouse[i])`, right? So watch out where to put it and how to use this post which is the idea and the fix for your issue

Comment: @AzmainSyed if this answer helped you to solve your current issue, you might want to accept it so that other can also benefit from this answer.